# "Failed to notify dependency resolution listener." Error when importing FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebaseui

When I implement firebaseui, I encounter this error:

```
Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement is being requested by various other libraries at [[11.0.2,11.0.2], [15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 15.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.
```

And this is my dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.1.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `./gradlew app:dependencies` in the Android Studio terminal will let you know which dependencies are having different versions. However, you can try updating all related dependencies.

In your root `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
    ...
```

In the app `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:2.1.0'
```

Then try to rebuild the project. This should solve the issue most of the times, also make sure you have added:

```
 repositories {
        // ...
        google() // Google's Maven repository
    }
```

In the root `build.gradle`.