# Android Studio 4.0 update

Tags: android-studio, flutter

Currently a student working through a chat app module with appBrewery.  All working well until I updated to the latest Studio then this gets thrown up.

Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

> Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
>   tried to access method sun.security.util.ECUtil.getECParameters(Ljava/security/Provider;)Ljava/security/AlgorithmParameters; from class sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator

Any ideas?

Comment: Similar Questions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52912781/failed-to-notify-dependency-resolution-listener-error-when-importing-firebase

Answer (score 7):

It is because of some file got corrupted while installing Android 4.0. So, doing Invalidate cache and restart will help you... After restart it will automatically download the corrupted files.

Comment: I try to do for Flutter, but not work. Who can help me?

Comment: This worked for me in a CapacitorJS project after upgrading from Android Studio 3.5 to 4.1 on a Mac, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Probably something went wrong during the update. 
My andorid studio had problems connecting to internet (gave me an error when trying to check for updates and the plugin marketplace wouldn't show anything). If yours does the same then there's a good chance you can fix it like this:

- Download the latest installer (if you don't have it already) and install it making sure that you confirm you want to delete your old installation when it asks
- Once installed, if you have any notifications under the "configure" menu on android studio's welcome screen that asks to update something, update it and then restart android studio.
- Done!

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks I would have tried that if i'd have read it earlier. My laptop being less than 2 weeks old I opted for a factory reset, did the trick and now both emulators work with the Firebase module which is a bonus.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this issue, and if it helps anyone, in
`app/build.gradle` file make sure that `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` are the same.  I had `28` and `29` respectively, and when I changed the former to `29` the app built fine.