# Why does failed to notify dependency resolution listener error come in flutter?

Tags: java, android-studio, flutter, gradle, dart

I updated my Android Studio and am getting this error: -

```
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to notify dependency resolution listener.
   > tried to access method sun.security.util.ECUtil.getECParameters
     (Ljava/security/Provider;)
     Ljava/security/AlgorithmParameters; from class 
     sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator
```

I tried whats mentioned at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62089212/android-studio-4-0-update), but this does not resolve my error. This comes as soon as you add dependency `flutter_login_facebook: ^0.1.2+2` in `pubspec.yaml` and try to `flutter run`.

Comment: did you manage to solve this?